# Listen to Solidity Events using in Javascript using the UseDapp(React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js

I am using the useDapp react Library to call a function on a Solidity using the useContractFunction.

```
 const { state, send, events } = useContractFunction(CreateERC20Contract, 'createToken', { transactionName: 'create a new erc20 token' })
```

I want to listen to events created by the smart contract in the React front-end using useDapp or any other library I can integrate with useDapp. I will be grateful if anyone has an Idea on how solidity contract events can be listened to using useDapp.

Answer (score 1):

UseDapp has a recent addition for this, a hook named `useLogs`.

I invite you to [take a look](https://usedapp-docs.netlify.app/docs/API%20Reference/Hooks#uselogs) and see if it works for your use case.

#### Example

This will download all `Transfer` events from an instance of a `token` contract, and print out transaction hash and data for every event.

```
const logs = useLogs(
  {
    contract: token,
    event: 'Transfer',
    args: [],
  },
  {
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest',
  }
)

logs?.value?.forEach((log) => {
  console.log(log.transactionHash)
  console.log(log.data)
})
```

It's best to narrow down the amount of blocks you inspect using the `fromBlock` and `toBlock` parameters otherwise the query might get too big for the RPC provider. You can also use `blockHash` to target specific block.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to listen to events is by using [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/).